# How write a list in a .txt file with R

Tags: r, list

I would like to write in a `.txt` file the following list:

```
[[1]]

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7   15 
3430  145   29    6    1    3    2    1 

[[2]]

  1    2    3    4    5   13   22 
3162   97   16    6    2    1    1 

[[3]]

  1    2    3    5    6   12  
1659   83   15    2    2    1
```

as you can see above. I tried with

```
lapply(mylist, write, "test.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
```

but I obtained wrong result:

```
3430 145 29 6 1 3 2 1
3162 97 16 6 2 1 1
1659 83 15 2 2 1
```

(some of the data have been deleted).

Comment: @RonakShah: Only 1 text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lI assume you mean that in your example the names were not printed to the file? An easy but somewhat "hackish" way (but that achieves exactly the output as in your example) would be to use sink():

```
sink(file = "output.txt")
print(mylist)
sink(NULL)
```

Edit:
Explanaiton

```
sink(file = "output.txt")
```

redirects (almost) all output in the following lines to the file specified

```
print(mylist)
```

prints normally to stdout, but since sink() is "active" its printed to the file (exactly the content that would otherwise printed to the console)

```
sink(NULL)
```

deactivates the redirect.
See

```
?sink()
```

for additional information.